# ios excel format number with color

Tags: ios, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to format numbers in an excel document built with PHPExcel so negative number have parenthesis around them and are red and positive numbers are green.

```
$worksheet->getStyle("A1")->applyFromArray({
    "numberformat" => [
        "code" => "[green]#,##0.00;[red](#,##0.00)",
    ]
});
```

Everything works great except on iOS.

iOS changes the formatted cells to `[241498718990]` no matter what the actual number is.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does ios accept that format from Excel files created in MS Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the color from the format option and adding a font color option

```
$worksheet->getStyle("A1")->applyFromArray({
    "font" => [
        "color" => [
            "rgb" => ($value < 0 ? "ff0000" : "00ff00")
        ]
    ],
    "numberformat" => [
        "code" => "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)",
    ]
});
```

This only works if you know whether the value is less than 0 and know that the value won't be changed in the excel document.